# How to make a 2D map similar to a 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary, 2d

Is it possible to make a 2d map?

Like this:

```cpp
map< int, int, string> testMap;
```

And filling the values would be like:

```cpp
testMap[1][3] = "Hello";
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can nest two maps:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::map<int,std::map<int,std::string>> m;

    m[1][3] = "Hello";

    std::cout << m[1][3] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 26):

**yes, use `std::pair`** within a `std::map`,

```
std::map< std::pair<int, int>, string> testMap;
testMap[std::make_pair(1,3)] = "Hello";
```

Comment: Interesting. Normally, I might use this, however I'm actually using Qt creator so I don't think they have the standard library. They might have something similar, but idk. For example, instead of using std::map, I'm using QMap. Good thing the syntax was the same

Comment: Qt Creator is just an IDE (integrated development environment), not a compiler or different form of C++.  So, even though Qt Creator is useful when dealing with the Qt library, which defines QMap, you can still write standard C++ (e.g. using std::map) in Qt Creator and compile it just fine.

Comment: This will be considerably more efficient than RyanMcK's solution.

Comment: In what way will this be more efficient?

Comment: @mc360pro a `std::pair` is not as heavy as adding an extra `std::map`. The look up time for a map of maps is `O(Lg(n)*Lg(n))` while a pair only take `O(Lg(n))`.

Comment: It is definitely not `O(lg(n)*lg(n))`. It's `O(lg(n) + lg(n))`, or just `O(lg(n))`. The first map lookup takes `lg(n)`, and the second also takes `lg(n)`. Of course, this is assuming a square "array." This should probably be broken down into `m` and `n` instead, but it still simplifies in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 2):

In case it's helpful for anybody, here is code for a class that builds upon andre's answer, which allows access via bracket operators like a regular 2D array would:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Graph {
/*
    Generic Graph ADT that uses a map for large, sparse graphs which can be
    accessed like an arbitrarily-sized 2d array in logarithmic time.
*/
private:
    typedef std::map<std::pair<size_t, size_t>, T> graph_type;
    graph_type graph;
    class SrcVertex {
    private:
        graph_type& graph;
        size_t vert_src;
    public:
        SrcVertex(graph_type& graph): graph(graph) {}
        T& operator[](size_t vert_dst) {
            return graph[std::make_pair(vert_src, vert_dst)];
        }
        void set_vert_src(size_t vert_src) {
            this->vert_src = vert_src;
        }
    } src_vertex_proxy;
public:
    Graph(): src_vertex_proxy(graph) {}
    SrcVertex& operator[](size_t vert_src) {
        src_vertex_proxy.set_vert_src(vert_src);
        return src_vertex_proxy;
    }
};
```