# Two-dimension unordered_map in C++

Tags: c++, unordered-map

Im new in C++, I figured out how to use 1 dimensional unordered map:

```
unordered_map<string, int> dictionary;
dictionary[word]++;//Simple adding word to dictionary and increasing count of that word.
```

In python I could do 2-dimensional boolean hash-table simple with:

```
cache ={}
cache([5,11])=true
cache([100,1])=false
//And then i can work with hash-table:
if ([i,j]) in cache:
    retrun cache([i,j])
```

Could you help me, how does it works in C++?

I want to make two-dimensional hash table like that:

```
unordered_map<int, int, bool> dictionary;
dictionary[1][3] = true; dictionary[7][5] = false;
if (dictionary.find([i][j]) != dict_reference.end())
{//Pair in dictionary
}
```

It ofc dont work in C++.

Comment: Use `std::unordered_map<std::pair<int, int>, bool>`. You can also use custom struct with sensible named members instead of `std::pair`

Comment: Also, the first google search I did gives many posts that has the exact same problem. [How to make a 2D map similar to a 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642882/how-to-make-a-2d-map-similar-to-a-2d-array). The downvote button recommends downvoting posts that does not show any research effort.

Comment: @user12002570 thx for advice, however if you new in C++ and your English is weak, this two problems multiply each other and googling anything more difficult than "Hello word" becomes real pain in the ass. Thats why I ask it here

Comment: @user12002570 No don't use pair. it is a type without any semantic meaning. Declare a custom struct with 2 members  eg. `struct my_key_t { int key_part1; int key_part2; };` that way you end up with code with better semantics and readability. Using std::pair is just the wrong kind of lazy

Comment: @MrLeyt1125 Note if I just copy/paste the title of your question into google, it will give the duplicates.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Yup, that's why I mentioned that as part of my first comment.

Comment: @user12002570 I saw you did. But you should imo give the prefered "solution" first ;)

Comment: @user12002570 you'te both ignoring fact that search engines today give differentpeople differentresults based on previous activity. Search should be trained and it also depends on location

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Yeah, that is also a factor. But a well-researched question would've find the duplicates. Even a little search would've found the dupes as this is common enough question and there are many posts.

Comment: @user12002570 For me the only match was this question. I guess, you've got others because you had visited them before. But "multi-dimensional map" gives me results

Comment: Here's the right way to learn C++: get a C++ textbook, open it to chapter 1, read the entire book. Here's the wrong way to learn C++: get a C++ textbook, read it partly, just enough to pick up the basic syntax and grammar, and attempt to figure out the rest by guessing, based on how some other, completely different, programming language works.

Comment: @Pepijn Kramer  Ive tried your suggestion, got error:  
error: static assertion failed: hash function must be invocable with an argument of key type
My code:
struct coordinates { int i; int j; };
unordered_map<coordinates, bool> cache;

Comment: That's expected you need to override std::hash for your struct and probably implement `bool operator=(const coordinats& rhs)` too. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash has an example

Comment: @Pepijn Kramer damn dude, I just want to use user-friendly data type in my shitty project rather than studying a PhD thesis on programming

Comment: This is about as "user friendly" as you can expect from C++. You need to be very precise. And being able to read cppreference is kind of what comes with the terrritory

Comment: This is what it looks like in practice : https://onlinegdb.com/TUZe65Hh8. I would say it is not too bad. And your choice, but using std::pair is a shortcut  and you are not using the full benefit of C++'s type system. Be as explicit as you can be... one std::pair<int,int> can mean something totally different then another std::pair<int,int> and your compiler will not notice.

Comment: @Pepijn Kramer I found out that calling several times make_pair(i,j) takes takes too long. And then I just started using vector<vector<int>> to store my cache,  insttead of pair<int, int>, bool>
Thank you for providing the code, I don’t know anything about templates and overriding standard functions yet, but I saved it and someday I will be able to understand and use it in my projects

Comment: You're welcome. There is two (or more) levels of template understanding. The first level is being able to use them, which should not be hard and is really needed to use the standard library.  For your code you can also use the non-templated version of hash, also shown in the [struct MyHash in the hash documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash).  Anyway.. learning C++ does take time. I am using C++ for 30 years now and still learning (partially because C++ keep evolving).